# does 64 bit code take up more storage space that 32 bit code?

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

Sorry, I'm not long on S/O and a total newb at asm.

I've been reading over the Intel, Amd and nasm docs, ref.x86asm.net, sandpile.org, and wiki.osdev.org.

One thing I can't quite appreciate is whether:

1. 64 bit instructions are actually bigger (in long mode) than 32 bit instructions (in protected mode) because of prefixes... or whether the instructions are the same width?
2. And when the operands are given, they are often zero-padded (automatically), but is this done by the assembler at compile time or the processor at runtime?

Sorry if this is really obvious...

Comment: If each instruction does more work, you might need *fewer* instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just assemble some code or read the instruction set reference. Yeah, 64 bit operations and accessing new registers require a REX prefix so that does make code longer. 32 bit operations in 64 bit mode stay the same length:

```
 89 D8     mov eax, ebx ; normal size 2 bytes
 41 89 D8  mov r8d, ebx ; REX prefix to access r8d
 48 89 D8  mov rax, rbx ; REX prefix to use 64 bit size
```

Zero extension happens in hardware if you only write the low 32 bits of a 64 bit register.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic instruction:

```
mov ax, 0x1
```

I compiled with [BITS 32] or [BITS 64] and the result is:

```
66 B8 01 00
```

in both cases.  So I guess means at least for mov there's no difference.